# Login failed for user error on one page only

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

In my site, I am trying to loop through a list view and insert information into my database. However, when I run the site, I get

> Cannot open user default database. Login failed. Login failed for
>   user.... (my user name)

The only thing is, on another page that I have an insert command, it works fine, and I am able to access data from the database without any issues.

The code that I am attempting to use is:

```
Guid InsertID = System.Guid.NewGuid();
        String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
        var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand insertCMD = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Orders (Order_ID, Item_ID, QTY, Price_Per_Unit, Total_Price) VALUES (@Order_ID, @Item_ID, @QTY, @Price_Per_Unit, @Total_Price)", myConnection);
        insertCMD.Connection.Open();

        foreach (ListViewItem item in ItemLV.Items)
        {
            TextBox QTY = (TextBox)item.FindControl("QTYTB");
            int InsertQTY = int.Parse(QTY.Text);

            if (InsertQTY > 0)
            {
                Label Price = (Label)item.FindControl("PriceLabel");
                HiddenField ItemID = (HiddenField)item.FindControl("IDHF");

                Decimal InsertPrice = Decimal.Parse(Price.Text.Substring(1));
                Guid InsertItemID = Guid.Parse(ItemID.Value);
                Decimal InsertTotalPrice = InsertPrice * InsertQTY;

                insertCMD.Parameters.Clear();
                insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Order_ID", InsertID);
                insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Item_ID", InsertItemID);
                insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@QTY", InsertQTY);
                insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price_Per_Unit", InsertPrice);
                insertCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Total_Price", InsertTotalPrice);

                try
                {
                    insertCMD.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Order/Error.aspx");
                }
                finally
                {

                }
            }
        }

        insertCMD.Connection.Close();
```

This code throws me the error outlined above, yet, on my registration page (using the same code as this less the 'foreach' loop and with a different command and parameters), it works without an issue. So, I am assuming it isn't really to do with my user not having access to the database, but perhaps a problem with my code.

The stack trace is as follows:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open user default database. Login
>   failed. Login failed for user (my user account).]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5295167    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +242
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1682
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +69
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK) +30
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +317
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +889
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions) +434
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +225
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +558
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions) +67
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +83    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>   Order_Order.ContinueBTN_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   m:\OrderingSystem\Order\Order.aspx.cs:36
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553594
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +103
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724

EDIT:

My connection string in my web.config file is:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\WebSite2013;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Ordering_System_Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

and the working code from my registration page is:

```
    String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LocalSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
                        var myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer_Profiles(UID, First_Name, Last_Name, State_ID, Country_ID, Phone_Number, Mobile_Number, Date_of_Birth) VALUES(@UID, @First_Name, @Last_Name, @State_ID, @Country_ID, @Phone_Number, @Mobile_Number, @Date_of_Birth)", myConnection);
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UID", newUserGuid);
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", FirstNameTB.Text);
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", LastNameTB.Text);
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State_ID", StateDDL.SelectedValue);
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country_ID", CountryDDL.SelectedValue);
                                if (PhoneTB.Text.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone_Number", PhoneTB.Text);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone_Number", DBNull.Value);
                                }
                                if (MobileTB.Text.Length > 0)
                                {
                                    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile_Number", MobileTB.Text);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile_Number", DBNull.Value);
                                }
                                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_of_Birth", BirthDay);
                                try
                                {
                                    insertUser.Connection.Open();
                                    insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    insertUser.Connection.Close();

                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
                                }
                            }
```

I have since experimented a bit and added test select and insert queries and discovered that it seems to be only for this page that the errors are occurring, no matter what query I use, yet on all the other pages in my website it will work fine.

Comment: If you haven't already confirm that your connection string name is "LocalSqlServer" in your web config. It would be great if you could post your connection string and the working code as well. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my post with the requested code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to those who helped, I managed to determine that the problem was actually the connection strings being used by my ListViews - it was attaching my database as a local database instead of using my server instance as it does in the web.config file.

For anyone in the future with this issue, check that any SqlDataSources implemented on your page use the same connection string as that in your web.config file - I have now done this:

```
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LocalSqlServer %>"
```

And the way you'll be able to tell if it is something to do with the page and not the database, is because it will only happen on one page or certain pages (as it did for me).